# Adding elements to a ListView expands it below other elements using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-listview, xml-layout

In my activity i hava a ListView which has an ArrayAdapter as its adapter, and is updated dynamically. I am using RelativeLayout. At first, the ListView is empty, but I can see that it takes up space on the screen compared to before i added it. As soon as one element is added, it is expanded and shows this element. As soon as I add a second element, I only see the top of the second element and then it goes behind the message text element under. How can I solve this?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAddAttachment"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/sprType"
    android:text="Add attachment"/>

<!--ATTACHMENTS LIST-->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstAttachments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnAddAttachment">
</ListView>

<!-- MESSAGE TEXT -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/lstAttachments"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:lines="10"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:maxLength="500"
    android:hint="Message text"
    android:gravity="top|left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `android:layout_height` value of the `RelativeLayout`?

Try changing the `ListView` to have:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

and do the same for the `RelativeLayout` that contains it.

You can then align the `EditText` below it to the bottom of the `ListView`, and make sure the list view is `layout_above` that `EditText`

Comment: If you align the ListView to be layout_above the EditText, and the EditText to be below the ListView, I would get a circular reference. Did I understand you correctly?